# java running threads simultaniously

Tags: java, multithreading

Im working on a elevator simulator, in wich i have to simulate the work of 4 elevators in a building. Well, at first i thought it was easy, 4 threads and its all good. but im running into trouble because my threads won't run at the same time, even with infinite cycles only one thread runs at a time.

```
@Override
public void run() {


    while (true)
    {
    int i = rand.nextInt(p1.getNFloors());
    building.getFloors().get(i).putPersons();
    System.out.println(building.toString());

     try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Relogio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

and on a seperate thread :

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true)
    {

    for (int i = 0; i < building.getFloors().size(); i++)
    {

        if (building.getFloors().get(i).getPersons().size() != 0)
        {
            building.getFloors().get(i).callElevator();  //this should call 1 elevator
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Thread1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and i have 4 instances of this thread running (therefor i have 4 elevators)

the problem is: only 1 thread runs at a time, so only 1 elevator at a time.

btw, the callElevator method gets the elevator from an arrayList in wich i have 4 elevators stored. the condition that needs to be met is if the elevator is stopped he can be called.

the way i start the threads:

the first thread (the one that puts people in the floors): thread.start(); 
and after that , i initialize 4 instances of the thread that calls the elevators.

so it looks like this:

```
Simulator s1 = new Simulator();
ElevatorThread et1 = new ElevatorThread();
ElevatorThread et2 = new ElevatorThread();
ElevatorThread et3 = new ElevatorThread();
ElevatorThread et4 = new ElevatorThread();
s1.start(); 
et1.start();
et2.start();
et3.start();
et4.start();
```

both threads extends Thread. 
any tips?

Comment: How are you determining that only one runs at a time?

Comment: How do you know only one is running? how do you start the threads? we need more information...

Comment: i know because the toString tells me. i have the building representation on console. and only 1 elevator does its job at a time. ill edit the post and tell you how i start the threads

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information here to see how you can determine that just from that one `println` statement.  I would suggest constructing a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: oh, the thing thats happenning now is that the first thread runs and the others dont. as if they weren't threads. the first thread keeps generating ppl and the elevators never work. it could be something related with the elevator class code, but without the threads and using just one elevator everything is fine.

Comment: Assuming that the first run method is from ElevatorThread, and that all elevators share the same building instance, then `System.out.println(building.toString());` will produce the same output for each thread.  There's not enough diagnostic info in your output to analyse how the threads are running.  Try adding more System.out.println calls, with each one quoting the Thread's name (or some other unique identifier).

Comment: Are you using `volatile`, `synchronized`, or a java.util.concurrent class anywhere?  [The Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) states that the JVM is free to optimize execution by assuming the value of a non-volatile, unsynchronized field has not changed unless the currently executing thread changes it.  You might benefit from changing each ArrayList to a CopyOnWriteArrayList or a Vector.

Comment: they generate the same output except for the elevator positions. and only 1 elevator moves. if 4 floors call the elevator at the same time, they should all move. what the program is doing is it waits for the action of the first elevator to end and then calls another elevator ( wich will be the same because it will be stopped and in the 1st position of the array)

Comment: if your problem is that "the program ... waits for the action of the first elevator to end and then calls another elevator", can you post your callElevator() method? perhaps there is something wrong with callElevator()?

Comment: You "produce" a person per second..and each thread "consume" a person per second as well. Why there should be more than zone thread active? Try reducing the sleep in simulator to 100ms

Comment: Also be sure to use thread safe list for your shared stuff